# Java: How to create simple method

Tags: java, sockets, methods

I have a simple Java program. Program connects to the server and send the numbers. I would like to redo the program that the number was sent by pressing a button.

Button code:

```
/* button */
JButton b1;
b1 = new JButton("Send");
b1.addActionListener(this);

/* ActionListener */

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent zdarzenie)
    {
        Object zrodlo = zdarzenie.getSource();
        if (zrodlo == b1){
          sendNumber(number) <------- THIS METHOD
        }
    }
```

And here I need to create method sendNumber

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Client
{
    private Socket socket;

    Client()
    {
        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 2020);
            System.out.println("Klient dziala");
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Uruchom serwer");
            System.exit(1);
        }
     }

     void uruchom() throws Exception
     {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                            new OutputStreamWriter(
                                socket.getOutputStream()),true);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                                socket.getInputStream()));

        Scanner czytacz = new Scanner(System.in);

        String liczba, odSerwera;
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Podaj zgadywaną liczbę: ");
            liczba = czytacz.nextLine();
            out.println(liczba);

            odSerwera = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(odSerwera);
            if(odSerwera.equals("Zgadłeś")) break;
        }

        socket.close();
     }

     public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
     {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.uruchom();
     }
}
```

I tried this:

```
void sendNumber(String number)
    {
        out.println(number);
    }
```

Unfortunately this is not working. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding listener as follows:

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Execute when button is pressed
            sendNumber(number);
        }
    });
```

Comment: At the beginning I have to create a method sendNumber and i dont know how.